# doneRendering can't call other functions in the controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I wanted to call a function out of the controller "doneRendering"

CMP file:

```
<aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doneRendering}"/>
```

Controller:

```
    doneRendering: function(component) {....}
```

But every time I include a function (that is not even in the helper file) I end up getting the function undefined error.  Has anyone figured out a way around that?

Comment: Curious exactly what you are trying to do. Is it something like this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88492/how-to-find-out-when-aura-component-document-is-ready